# Оптимизация выборки из List большого объема

Tags: c#, циклы, list, список

Всем добрый день! У меня есть список координат, где хранятся больше 100к записей. Я прохожу этот список двойным циклом для нахождения одинаковых записей, которые нужно подсчитать. Ниже привожу код, который я использую:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedPointsInBin.Count; i++)
{
    double coordX = 0, coordY = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < selectedPointsInBin.Count; j++)
    {
        if (selectedPointsInBin[i].PointX == selectedPointsInBin[j].PointX && selectedPointsInBin[i].PointY == selectedPointsInBin[j].PointY)
        {
            countPoints++;
            coordX = selectedPointsInBin[i].PointX;
            coordY = selectedPointsInBin[i].PointY;
        }
    }
    PointsSelectedObjects points = new PointsSelectedObjects(coordX, coordY, countPoints);
    countSelectedPointsInBin.Add(points);
    countPoints = 0;
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь это оптимизировать, а то когда там 100-200к записей цикл выполняется продолжительное время

Comment: Огорчу: сравнивать вещественные (double) числа напрямую (==) неверно! Если сравнивать правильно, с использованием погрешности эпсилон, процесс ещё замедлится...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сгруппируйте по паре координат, и посчитайте количество точек в каждой группе:

```
countSelectedPointsInBin = selectedPointsInBin
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.PointX, p.PointY })
    .Select(g => new PointsSelectedObjects(g.Key.PointX, g.Key.PointY, g.Count()))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не добавить параллелизм?

Список хранится в памяти=> какой-нибудь параллельный перебор ускорит обработку в несколько раз.

Если элемент совпадает то сохраняйте в какой-нибудь списке, где будет 2 элемента, которые будут являться парами совпавших индексов списков.

Можно еще попробовать отказаться от вещественных чисел и хранить дробь в одной INT переменной, а целое в другой INT переменной. Вроде, так работает Windows.